# 2 events after click function in jquery

Tags: jquery

What i'm tring to achieve is performing 2 actions after clicking a link
 - one after another

- first, go to certain page
- then, smooth scroll down and focus on textarea on that page

Both pages are on my domain. Have this so far but doesn't quite work:

```
    jQuery('.link').click(function() {
        window.location.href = 'http://example.com/page';
    });
    jQuery('.link').click(function() {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery('.textarea').offset().top-220
        }, 700, function(){jQuery('.textarea').focus();});
    });
```

Comment: Is this external page out of your domain? If so, you cannot control anything, even scrolling to a specific point on it. If the page is in your domain, e.g. you have both pages on your local drive, then you should probably put the jquery animation in the javascript of your second page.

Comment: Do you control the code on the second page being loadded?

Comment: both pages are on my domain

Comment: You will have to do the second functionality on the new page. As soon as the new page is loading, the old page's Javascripts are completely gone and out of effect.

Comment: So do the scroll animation in code on second page

Comment: Put the scrolling code on the other page

Comment: When you assign to `window.location.href`, that reloads the page and all scripts on the original page stop running. And even if they didn't, they would be operating on the first page's DOM, not the new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because after changing location to the new page, your script is re-loaded and the context of the `click` event is lost. If you want the (new) page to scroll every time it is visited, then you could simply set the second function to it's `onload` event. If you want it to scroll down only if it is visited through that specific link, then you can maybe add a parameter to the url on the link's `href` and by fetching that parameter on that new page, you can determine whether it has been visited through that link and scroll accordingly.

```
jQuery('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location = 'http://example.com/page/#/scroll';
});

var pageUrl = location;
if(String(pageUrl).substr(-8) == "#/scroll") {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery('.textarea').offset().top-220
    }, 700, function(){jQuery('.textarea').focus();});
}
```

See what I mean by visiting these links (view source for script) :-

No scrolling - http://s.codepen.io/cod3rguy/debug/vgBpEb/

Scrolling - http://s.codepen.io/cod3rguy/debug/vgBpEb/#/scroll

Comment: Awesome, works great. Thanks for detailed explanation.

Comment: @benua Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you navigate to the new page, `window.location.href`, the current context is lost; the second scroll logic will not work. Maybe you should do the scroll logic in the new page instead of having it in the click event.

You might need to differentiate between whether you need auto scroll in the new page, you could pass a query string for that something like - `http://example.com/page?scroll=true` - and in that page load, you can check the query string and perform  the scroll logic.

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to use 2 functions for that. In the first function body include the second function's body.

Comment: script on first page will not run on second page. This answer is not going to work

Comment: No, it's an external page. We need to know whether or not the page is out of the OP's domain.

Comment: both pages are on my domain

Comment: Oh sorry,I didn't notice op has mentioned "that page".My bad!